# Android activity stack -Open SearchActivity by only keeping HomeActvity in stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 4 activities

1)**HomeActivity**

2)**SubActivity1**

3)**SubActivity2**

4)**SearchActivity**

And the app flow is `HomeActivity->SubActivity1->SubActitvity2`.

Search Option is present in every screen,so 
When a user in `SubActivity2` does search and opens `SearchActvity`

Then i need my app to have stack as
`HomeActvity->searchActvity` and not as `HomeActivity->SubActivity1->SubActitvity2->searchActvity`

How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read here and this all is explained.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Check out how to "re order" the back stack.